# Where to submit an article exposing widespread fraud in academia?

Tags: publications, cheating

Where would be the best place to submit an article for publication arguing that the conventional mathematics curriculum including calculus and the courses leading up to it (i.e. most of secondary-school mathematics) is fraudulent?

**Note inspired by comments posted below:** My question was **where** to submit such a publication.  My question was **not** whether the thesis of the publication is true.  This is something I have been thinking about since 1978, and I have been teaching calculus and its prerequisite subjects since that time, and published on calculus teaching.  Comments below suggesting I am rashly commenting on a subject I haven't thought about are mistaken.

Could those who have down-voted the question explain what their objections are?  The comments make me suspect that some of them result from disagreement with the thesis of the proposed paper.  But the question was only about the appropriate forum for publication and I made no attempt to support the thesis, since that would be off topic.  Is this getting down-voted for off-topic reasons?

Comment: I doubt you will get anywhere arguing "fraudulence." You could argue that it's not optimal (and I know people such as [Benoît Mandelbrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benoit_Mandelbrot) who would agree with you), but to argue that the courses are _fraudulent_ would be to say that they're teaching false or misleading information, which just isn't the case.

Comment: @aeismail: *they're teaching false or misleading information* – It’s even worse; it would mean that they are **intentionally** doing this. If this actually were the case, it would be impossible to publish this article in any peer-reviewed journal, as the potential editors and reviewers are involved in the fraud.

Comment: Reminder: extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof.

Comment: @aeismail : They are indeed teaching falsehoods.  They are teaching that mathematics consists of algorithms. They give you an algorithm for solving assigned problems #1 through 10 and in effect teach, without explicitly saying so, that doing that sort of thing is what mathematics is.  Poll 100 non-mathematicians and I won't be surprised if you find that all of them say that they were taught in school that that is what mathematics consists of.  Add to that the fact that students who aren't remotenly.....

Comment: ...prepared to understand calculus are encouraged to take calculus, and have been give grades of "A+" in prerequisite courses, and the faculty generally knows that such students don't even begin to have any awareness of the prerequisite material, and then the course is adapted so that such students can get good grades in it, the adaptation consisting of just giving them procedures to be mechanically followed to get answers to assign problems, and students graduate from college in effect having been taught that that is what mathematics is. Falsehoods about the subject of the course are taught.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : This is something I have thought about for decades.  Please see my two foregoing comments.

Comment: Ok, I think i see the angle you're approaching it from. Could be an interesting discussion of pedagogical principles and approaches, if you didn't drive away the readers you should be trying to reach. Peter's absolutely right about that; you need to squelch the indignation or it's too easy to write you off as a crank. Focus on what could be done better and why it would be better,  rather than accusing folks.

Comment: Still, what you are referring to is not fraud; it’s at worst bad didactics. (Besides, what you describe is not globally applicable. I was not taught mathematics like this.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : Have I been disrespectful?  You start from the presumption that I haven't thought about things I am saying.  There is nothing in codified standards that says one should teach that mathematics consists of algorithms.  No one says it explicitly.  It's silly to expect to find it in codified standards.  You will find lots of people who admit that it is true and say they wish they could do something about it.  Professors of mathematics are not entitled to say they wish they could do something: they are the ones who can.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft : I am aware that mathematics is not _always_ taught that way, and indeed it was not taught that way to me, nor is it taught that way in courses in which the students are there because they want to learn mathematics.  It is taught that way in classes where the students work hard and pride themselves on good grades and whose motive for being there is to polish their resumes and impress schools and employers they will apply to.

Comment: These comments have seem to be about the merits of my claim about fraud, and don't seem to contemplate the actual question I asked.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : I would also prefer to avoid this particular discussion here, since it doesn't address the question I asked.  The question was: which forums are appropriate for such a publication, if it is to be published?

Comment: A couple of decades ago [you could have circulated it as a pre-print among the academe and eventually expanded it into a book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician%27s_Lament). Now you'll just be seen as (a) riding on Lockhart's coat tails and (b) hyperbolic.

Comment: @dmckee : Fortunately I will not duplicate Lockhart's thesis, although I agree with it.  Pete L. Clark says he would pay attention to something that begins by saying "Here is a serious, widespread and insidious problem with the conventional mathematics curriculum".  One thing on which I agree with Lockhart is that a big problem with the mathematics curriculum is that it is a curriculum.  Curricula should be abolished.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23627/discussion-on-question-by-michael-hardy-where-to-submit-an-article-exposing-wide).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking specific advice on how to proceed in a specific field of academia, not asking about academia as a whole.

Comment: A partial answer to your actual question: Not here.

Comment: I think is question is not a very good fit for us. I think where to publish something is both opinion based and too specific.

Comment: In one of Feynman's books he mentions showing a flexible curve to his math class and pointing out its "surprising" property that the tangent is always horizontal at its lowest point. His point is to illustrate that the class were differentiating functions and finding minima without any genuine understanding. If passing such students is the sort of "fraudulent" behaviour that the OP refers to then I agree with him, but it's not the best choice of adjective.

Comment: @TheMathemagician : That students without ability show up is not fraud.  That they are encouraged to show up, and tacitly but effectively and emphatically taught over the course of years that mathematics consists only of algorithms, and that is done only to fill up classrooms in order to get tuition money, is fraud.  And it's far worse than just that.

Comment: @ToddWilcox : duh.  Obviously I would not attempt to put such a thing here.  I've never hinted at making the case for that proposition here.  What is the occasion for posting your comment above?

Comment: @keshlam : You wrote "Focus on what could be done better and why it would be better, rather than accusing folks." Can that work of doing it better is something they don't want? When the substance of the accusation would be that they don't want it? And some of you comments here cause me to wonder what qualifications you claim. You seem to consider yourself competent to take a position on some of the matters I've raised. Of what does your competence in this area consist?

Answer (score 14):

The appropriate places to put an angry contrarian rant where you assert that a large percentage of scientists are doing it wrong are (in order of preference):

1. [arXiv.org](http://arxiv.org/), which will take pre-print papers from pretty much anybody with a well-established affiliation within their scope.
2. [viXra.org](http://vixra.org/), which will take independent paper from pretty much anybody.
3. A personal website extolling your particular theory at length (e.g., [Gene Ray's famous site](http://timecube.com/))

These are all good places to submit an article such as you describe.

Publishing such an article, however, may not cause much of the mathematical community to listen to you.  For that, you will have to dig deeper and try to understand how to speak the language of the people that you want to listen to you, such that you can establish credibility with them.  A good starting point might be to take one particular significant point, rather than the whole broad spectrum, and construct a study that produces quantifiable evidence for your position.  That then, written up in a manner that conforms to the standards of the community and [will not score highly on the crackpot index](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html).

Please understand that I am being serious in my response to you: it is possible that you *have* identified something significant (I have no idea, not being familiar with your assertions).  If so, however, you will need to be very strategic in your approach to presenting it effectively.

Comment: I don't intend it to be angry or contrarian, but I've observed in recent hours that it makes some people angry.  And I think their reaction is unreasonable, and in fact it surprised me.  What I would have expected is that people would feel their attention was called to something they hadn't noticed.  Except that I know that some have noticed and will agree.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, the word "fraud" has not only very negative connotations, it has negative denotations as well! It is used by the legal system as a term for a felony. If you don't want to seem contrarian, step one would be to avoid that word entirely. A great step two would be to write something that does very little in the way of criticizing what currently exists and instead is largely about how things could be made better. "I've got an idea that I think will help" is so much more positive than "what you're doing is criminal".

Comment: @ToddWilcox : Indeed, fraud is bad.  I don't think of what I'm doing as "contrarian" because I don't really expect anyone to disagree with it, although I do expect it to be news to some.

Comment: Since we haven't seen your definition of "the calculus curriculum", we can't answer that question. I suspect from what little has been said that the actual answer is going to be a science-vs-engineering or applied-vs-pure divide, with basic pedagogical philosophy disagreements about what mix should be the default. But I'm guessing, and discussion here wouldn't do justice to the topic, so outside of cautioning against absolutes in the real world and against the "if you disagree I must have explained it badly" trap, I'll shaddup again.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You keep using words like "obvious," but the matter is apparently not so clear to your listeners.  If you want to have an impact on the mathematics community, you need to think about how to present your case so that it *is* clear to those listeners.  A good start would be to post a draft paper on arXiv and ask mathematicians you know to critique it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Regardless of whether you expect anyone do disagree with you, clearly many do, including me. I tutor mathematics from third grade through undergraduate courses and I really have no idea what you're talking about. The public and private schools and universities in my area don't seem to follow this fraudulent curriculum you are concerned about at all, and neither do any of the home school materials I've seen (and I've seen many). This is the first I'm hearing about teaching that "math is only about algorithms". I worked with a ninth grader on a proof yesterday.

Comment: @ToddWilcox : You see quite a lot of the math-consists-of-algorithms ideology among those who ask questions on math.stackexchange.com.  In freshman calculus courses lots of students are people who treat learning math only as a price paid to get a grade to impress prospective employers.  They demand to be told in advance an _algorithm_ to find the solution to every homework problem (although they don't know the word "algorithm"). They don't know what theorems or proofs are and they don't want to. Knowing how to prove something doesn't give them any confidence that it's true, rather....

Comment: ...they demand and feel entitled to dogmatic assertions from authorities that they can rely on for that.  That's what goes on in flagship state universities.  Of course there are students of a different sort there as well, but lower-level courses are conducted in such a way as not to put any strain on those of the sort I described here.

Comment: Remember, students who come here to ask us to do their homework are by definition atypical, inferior students. Of course that subset just wants an answer. Null datum.

Comment: @keshlam : On average those who ask questions on math.stackexchange.com are far better than typical students.  Those who simply post homework problems do so not simply because they just want others to do their homework, but because they don't actually have questions about the subject.  They see something in heiroglyphis and have no idea what it says, and copy it.  But nobody likes doing that so that's why we see better-than-average students.

Comment: Uhm... I think you've just agreed with me that the subset you are complaining about are atypical.

Comment: @keshlam : They are atypical of those who post to stackexchange, but they are not atypical of those who show up in courses.  The system encourages unqualified students to sign up for courses.

Comment: @michaelhardy: We agree that we disagree. Strongly.

Comment: @keshlam : Are you saying _typical_ students in calculus courses are not learning as a price of a grade, but learning because they want to understand regardless of whether it gets them a grade, and know that mathematics isn't just algorithms for finding answers to assigned problems, etc., and are working toward understanding things independently of what authorities tell them?

Comment: Some of that, yes. Some no. Some of the nos are regrettable, some aren't, depending upon the needs of the students. "There are nine and sixty ways of constructing tribal lays, / And every single one of them is right!" And this is getting long enough that it should be taken to Chat again.

Comment: keshlam *And this is getting long enough that it should be taken to Chat again.*  Seconded.  @MichaelHardy, you're experienced enough on Math.SE that you should understand how things work on SE sites.

Comment: @PeteLClark wrote "If you cannot prove to my satisfaction that (i) this statement is a codified part of the mathematics education curriculum and (ii) that those who are responsible for designing the curriculum believe it to be false and put it in with the intention to deceive, then by no means have you demonstrated fraudulent behavior, and I would stop reading there."  If someone demonstates that grades are always based only on bribes, would it fail to demonstrate dishonesty if I cannot find a NCTM regulation saying that's what they should do?

Comment: @ToddWilcox : Just to be clear: The current conventional math curriculum is not just subotimal; it is evil.